# Are these usernames security threats?

Tags: support

I just saw a post on the site by a user with the username "gmail.com".  There is also an active user "yahoo.com".  Is this not a potential security threat for some cross-site scripting scenario?

Comment: Could you explain any example of potential cross-site scripting scenario with these username?

Comment: It's not an XSS issue, but I did wonder about these names as well. I'm not aware of any SE policy regarding impersonation of a brand though.

Comment: BTW, it’s the same user who used to be “yahoo.com” and is now “gmail.com” (and was “anonymous” before, I think).

Comment: @Andrew T.  if someone replies to that user by putting "@" before their username, I don't know how the partial parse of that message would go.    But even just because *I* don't know how this can be exploited, it doesn't mean that this shouldn't raise a red flag about someone potentially trying to probe the site's vulnerabilities.

Comment: @grovkin I would contend that does mean it shouldn't raise a red flag. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020 might be of interest.

Comment: `@` is not a special character in the context of web applications (only email, which is quite different). It's characters such as `<`, `>`, as well as some others that need to be dealt with for web security (and SE does that correctly). So this is not really an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://firebounty.com/bug-bounty-program/302/stack-exchange says to take any suspected problem to https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact and to NOT answer @AndrewT.

If there is a real issue report it, if you want to know what issues having weird usernames can cause and how to mitigate them in general take it to security.se.